# can i use tkinter without display environment

Tags: python, tkinter

Can i use tkinter without display environment?

I've found [Timeline](https://github.com/donkeyDau/Timeline) in github and ran it on my environment that has no display(console is available).

And I got below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./make_timeline.py", line 425, in <module>
timeline = Timeline(filename)
  File "./make_timeline.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.tk_root = Tkinter.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1854, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I want to change this python code to work without DISPLAY setting.

So I tried to change it not to use tkinter when DISPLAY is not set. But I have to change `get_text_metrics()`, too, and I wonder what is the best approach. `get_text_metrics()` is like below.

```
def get_text_metrics(self, family, size, text):
    font = None
    key = (family, size)
    if key in self.fonts:
        font = self.fonts[key]
    else:
        font = tkFont.Font(family=family, size=size)
        self.fonts[key] = font
    assert font is not None
    (w, h) = (font.measure(text), font.metrics('linespace'))
    return (w, h)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use tkinter without display environment?

No, you cannot. Tkinter requires a display. It can be a virtual display such as xvfb, but to tkinter it must be a valid X11 display, or the equivalent on Windows and OSX.